# how to iterate values in nested array in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I have a nested array like this.Inside roles I have two more objects with roleId and roleName.
My requirement to show both the roleName of two objects in UI. How to achieve this in reactjs?

```
0:Object
displayName: "User Two"
dob:null
email:null
firstName:"User"
gender:null
languageId:null
lastAccessedOn:null
lastName:"Two"
middleName:null
password:null
pin:null

roles:Array(2)
0:Object
roleId:"37d8f51d-09c9-4d55-9ab0-60d0d031b412"
roleName:"Theranos Manufacturing"
1:Object
roleId:"af4c1fd4-6a7b-4b3e-aad1-da5b372502d8"
roleName:"Theranos Master Admin"

length:2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your array is name is `data` and in that you have `objects` which contain and `key roles` which is again an array then, you can have nested map over them like

```
{data.map((item, index) => {
     return (
         <div>
              {item.roles.map(role, idx) => {
                  return <ul key={role.roleId}><li >{role.roleId}</li>
                         <li>{role.roleName}</li></ul>
              }}
         </div>
     )
})}
```